# CSS Animation "slide in from side" not working on Chrome

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm a little new to CSS animations, to apologies if this is a silly question :) I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="slideToView" rel="{{product}}">
    <div class="info" rel="{{product}}">
        Info
    </div>
    <div class="remove" rel="{{product}}">
        Remove
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

...and the following CSS:

```
/* slider option */

.slideToView {
    z-index: 1000000;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: -200px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}
.slideToView.visible {
    transition: 1.5s;
    right: 5px;
    -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.slideToView.dohide {
    transition: 1s;
    right: -200px;

    -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;

    animation: slide 0.5s backwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.slideToView .info {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: #b0b6bb;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-left: 1px solid #95ACBF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slideToView .remove {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: #ff0000;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}
/* end slider options */
```

If I run the code in Firefox, it works fine:

[image: Firefox before it slides out]

[image: Firefox once its pulled out]

However, in Chrome it slides out ok - but then it goes to the left of the page:

[image]

As I said, I'm quite new to using CSS animations - but AFAIK I have everything right.

You can see a basic example of this happening here:

https://jsfiddle.net/unbmajwv/3/

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `dohide` class to `slideToView` in the html. And add `opacity: 0` to the `.slideToView` class and `opacity: 1` to the `.slideToView.visible` class.

Updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unbmajwv/4/

Comment: Thanks - I still get the same issue in Chrome though?

Comment: I checked in chrome only. Your version of fiddle is jumping to the left. But my updated version works. Please double check it.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work for me. slide out simply "appears" (fades in). In case you're confused, it needs to come OUT of the right hand side, and go back "out of view" on the right when removed. Basically its for an app I'm doing, where it needs extra options to come into view when they swipe left/right

Comment: unfortunately not. Is there a temp place I can upload a video of what its doing?

Comment: please see this video I took. First (left) window is FF - 2nd is Chrome. http://andyapp.com.nmsrv.com/Video.avi . Sorry about the format, but its what the program I used to do the screencast saves as :)

Comment: Check this: Mac/chrome latest ver: http://libin.in/wp-test/wp-content/uploads/slideout.mov

Comment: Ok, well I think I found the issue. For some reason, Chrome didn't like: `-webkit-animation`. I commented that out in the *.dohide* and *.visible* classes, and now it works :)

Comment: Glad that you nailed it!